# Advance reporting is not working for Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.2.5, reports, advanced-reporting

**Advanced reporting** is not working for Magento 2.

I have followed all the **steps** as per the **Magento guideline**.

But the advance reporting is still not working.

Comment: I have followed all instruction given on Magento guideline.
URL: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/reports/advanced-reporting.html
https://nimb.ws/5G31mD
https://nimb.ws/5XiUAr
the advance reporting status is changed from pending to enabled
https://nimb.ws/mXhLG2

I have reauthorized the analytic user
https://nimb.ws/0rkEPl

waited for 2-3 days but the advance reporting leads to 404 page
https://nimb.ws/KUCAB6

Comment: Have you get the solution ? For enabling Advance Reporting.

Answer (score 0):

I am happy to inform you that there is a patch available to fix this issue in the core Magento installation, which I have attached here. Please upload the appropriate patch into your Magento root directory and run the SSH command below.

patch -p1 < MDVA-15136_EE_2.2.5_COMPOSER_v1.patch
or
patch -p1 < MDVA-15136_EE_2.2.5_v1.patch

Once that is done, refresh the cache in the Admin under "System > Cache Management" so that the changes will be reflected.

Please try it on a test environment first before taking it live, and kindly confirm that patch provided has resolved your issue.